# forcing a number to be displayed with 2 decimal places using swift

Tags: swift, text

I have a lot of code very similar to this.

```
//Gross Total
    var gt:Float64 = tp01 + tp02 + tp03 + tp04 + tp05 + tat + ntat
    GrossTotal.text = "\(gt)"
```

Where I display numbers in a label. This code works fine. I would like to know how to force the number being displayed to always have a value with exactly 2 decimal places. Please only swift code. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Swift String type has an initializer that takes a format string: `String(format:args:...)`

Your code might look like this:
    GrossTotal.text = String(format: "%.2f", gt)

EDIT: I had an "@" in front of the string, which is an Objective-C habit.
EDIT: Typing error resolved.

Comment: close enough. Thank you
this is what actually worked
    GrossTotal.text = NSString(format: "%.2f" , gt) as String

Comment: You don't need to cast it to String.    GrossTotal.text = String(format: "%.2f", gt)

Comment: Even better. Leonardo, you should post that as an answer and the OP should accept it.

Answer (score 5):

update: **Xcode 10.2 • Swift 5**

You can use NumberFormatter to format your string as desired and round it up or down as follow:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let number = NumberFormatter() 
}
```

---

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func fratcionDigitis(_ n: Int, roundingMode: NumberFormatter.RoundingMode = .halfEven) -> String {
        Formatter.number.roundingMode = roundingMode
        Formatter.number.maximumFractionDigits = n
        Formatter.number.minimumFractionDigits = n
        return Formatter.number.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let tp01 = 3.3232
let tp02 = 1.5673
let tp03 = 1.9764
let tp04 = 2.0986
let tp05 = 5.5557
let tat  = 2.7448
let ntat = 2.2339

let gt: Float64 = tp01 + tp02 + tp03 + tp04 + tp05 + tat + ntat   // 19.4999

let rounded = gt.fratcionDigitis(2)                        // "19.50"
let roundDown = gt.fratcionDigitis(2, roundingMode: .down) // "19.49"
let roundUp = gt.fratcionDigitis(2, roundingMode: .up)     // "19.50"
```

---

Or as I mentioned in my comment you can just use String(format:)

```
String(format: "%.2f", 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pretty slick extension for this:

Use: `GrossTotal.text = gt.format(2)`

Extension:

```
extension Double { // Same as Float64
    func format(f: Int) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.\(f)f", self)
    }
}
```

---

If you want to keep the value as a `Float64` and not a string you can also add this to your extension:

```
func roundTo(numDigits: Int) -> Double {
    let power = pow(10.0, Double(numDigits))
    return round(self * power) / power
}
```

Use: `gt.roundTo(2)` which returns a `Double`/`Float64` as the same type.

Comment: Your second "keep the value as Float64" method doesn't make sense. The mapping between decimal floating point and binary floating point isn't exact. Binary floating point values don't have an intrinsic number of decimal places. 64-bit Doubles are high enough in precision that they don't tend to have rounding errors when converted to strings, but the code you posed doesn't really do anything useful.